# Webpack tree shaking can’t extract unused function

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

When I use [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) and [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin), I try to minify code:

```
// this is test.js
export const ceil = Math.ceil

export const random = Math.random

// webpack entry
import { ceil } from './test'

export default ceil(3.3)
```

I got :

```
 // formated
 "use strict";
 n.d(t,"a",function(){return r});
 var r=Math.ceil;
 Math.random// still exist?
```

and if I minify

```
// this is test.js
export const ceil = Math.ceil

export const random = 1 // or string
```

I will get normal.

So, why `Math.random` still exist?
tree shaking not work?

webpack: 3.10.0
UglifyjsWebpackPlugin: 1.1.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear from your question, but `Math.random` is part of the javascript standard library, and is always included in every browser. As such, you can't tree shake it but you also don't need to worry about its size: you "get" `Math.random` for free.

Put another way, Tree shaking is a tool to reduce the size of your bundle. The definition for `Math.random` isn't part of your bundle to begin with, and it doesn't contribute to your bundle size.

*(note: the same is true of `Math.ceil`)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question about your answer: why I 'get' `Math.random`, if I write many `Math.random`, it won't add the size? I am so sorry I am't an english speaker, thanks for your time.

Comment: @JJJ `Math.random` returns a value. So with `const random = Math.random`, `random` is equal to a random value, it is not equal to the `Math.random` function. Tree shaking an app might remove `const random = Math.random`, if `const random` is never used, but it will not remove `Math.random` (because again, `Math.random` is provided by the browser). Notice how in your first minified example, `const random` was removed. Make sense?

Comment: Also, its a little unclear what part of your first minified example you added as a comment, but if a lone `Math.random` call was indeed still present after minification in your first example (i.e. the file ends simply with `Math.random` and you're questioning why the call to `Math.random` is still there), that I couldn't tell you. That might be an error in the tree shaking algorithm. I originally assumed that your first minified file looked like `"use strict"; n.d(t,"a",function({return r}); var r=Math.ceil;` and everything else was added by you as comments.